# How to detect a server in the network using JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, detection

Basically, I want to make a peer to peer architecture, using JavaScript (Ionic).

Since, JS cannot create sockets/etc; a NodeJS server has to be introduced between the clients; acting as the Socket.IO server between the clients.

The problem with this, is that the Socket.IO (NodeJS) server would need to be automatically found within the local network -- by the clients (instead of hardcoded/configured).

Are there any ways to implement such a thing; or alternatives to this architecture?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How does server detection work in other languages?

Comment: @Halcyon In Java e.g., broadcast packets could be sent over the network -- however, in this scenario this not possible, since the JS clients cannot receive packets (and cannot open ports).

Comment: If your local network is configured with its own DNS server then you can map your Node.JS server IP to a known hostname and keep it mapped even if the ip changes.

Comment: @apokryfos Not a bad idea! But I wish there is a more flexible solution for a rapid setup within any local network.

Comment: I'd suggest doing some searches about "resource discovery in a browser".

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem I don't think this can be done without at least 1 known point, be that a static hostname, static IP or something that both the server and clients can register themselves on (similar to how a P2P tracker is necessary for a P2P network). Worse case if you're on a 192.128.X.X network then there's only 65000 (more or less) IPs to check if you're bruteforcing it.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any ways to implement such a thing; or alternatives to this architecture?

Currently your architecture is using a browser app plus a Node app that users need to have on their network just to create TCP connections.

What you can do instead is create an Electron app that combines a Node app, a browser app, and a browser itself. See:

- https://electron.atom.io/

With Electron you can write your frontend code almost the same way as for the regular browser, but you can use the entire Node API including the TCP sockets so there will be no need to create a separate Node app and to search for that app in the network. This can greatly simplify your architecture.

Note: this is not an answer to the first part of the question: "How to detect a server in the network using JS?" but to the second part of the question: "Are there any ways to implement such a thing; or alternatives to this architecture?" Detecting the servers on the local network with client-side JavaScript will not be easy - and in fact it shouldn't be even possible because websites being able to scan your LAN for active services would be a serious problem for privacy and security.

Comment: Hm, but isn't electron only for desktop apps? I'm using electron for the desktop app version of the Ionic 2 app, however it also needs to run on iOS/Android/..

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem Yes, Electon is for desktop apps. You didn't say anything about iOS or Android in your question.